# check for specific characters in positional argument string using argparse add_argument()

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am a python newbie. I am trying to use argparse for one of my programs to parse the command line arguments. When I run the program I want to run it as : 

`prog.py /command:write`

now for the command line argument that I am giving here(/command:write), I use argparse to parse it. The constraint is that I just want the command line argument to contain one or more of only these :  characters, numbers, /, :,-,.,\,_

How do I specify this constraint in `add_argument()` function ?

Comment: any reason you can't go with the more standard `--command=write`?

Comment: Yes. Because this functionality has already been implemented in batch scripts, but since they are obsolete I am trying to implement the same in python scripts. Since people are already using this format, I can't change it now.

Comment: that is a very weird constraint for argparse, i don't think it can handle it. I would write the program in with nice options in standard format and write a helper scripts in sed to map from the odd format you need to use into standard format.

Comment: The above argument is just an example. My actual program has like 10-15 arguments. And I wanted to avoid manual parsing and error checking for each argument for each string.

Comment: The [prefix-chars](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars) argument to the `ArgumentParser` constructor can get you the `/` handling you want.

Comment: Yes you are right @user2357112. Thanks. The next problem is detecting the value of the command. Since it is delimited using ':' character and not the usual ' '.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter `sys.argv` before it is used by `parse_args`.

```
import sys
...
def foo(a):
   return a.replace('/','--').replace(':','=')

# '/command:write' => '--command=write'

argv = [foo(a) for a in sys.argv]
parse.parse_args(argv)
```

Use `re.sub` is you want more complex replacements